# Как задать путь до скрипта ссылкой?

Tags: node.js, ссылки, require

Мне нужно добавить несколько скриптов в один сервер на Node.js. Пока я использую файлы (пример:
`require('child_process').fork(__dirname + "/jquery.js");`
), но мне нужно обращаться к ссылкам типа https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js. Информации о таком способе я не нашел, как это сделать?

Comment: Вот тут можно подобрать приемлемый для тебя вариант решения - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809397/how-to-require-from-url-in-node-js